# Why Material-UI Dialog dismiss when pressing button on it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Why button `xxx` dismiss dialog? Isn't it possible to keep it open, but do some kind of login ofr button click?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ExpandMore from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import moment from "moment";
import axios from "axios";
import "../../assets/styles/BuyTicket.css";
import payment from "../../assets/images/payment.png";
import FacebookLogin from "react-facebook-login";
import { fbAppId, responseFacebook, getTempUserUuid } from "../../Utility";
import { Dialog, DialogActions, DialogContent } from "@material-ui/core";

function BuyTicket(props) {
  const jwt = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
  console.log(props.match);
  const eventTimeId = props.match.params.eventTimeId;
  const [numOfTickets, setNumOfTickets] = useState(1);
  const [searchedEventTime, setSearchedEventTime] = useState({});
  const [invoice, setInvoice] = useState(false);
  console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("searchedEventTimeList")));
  const searchedEventTimeList = JSON.parse(
    localStorage.getItem("searchedEventTimeList")
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchedEventTimeList) {
      setSearchedEventTime(searchedEventTimeList[eventTimeId]);
    } else {
      axios
        .post(`${window.baseUrl}search`, {
          tempUserUuid: getTempUserUuid(),
          eventTimeId
        })
        .then(data => {
          if (Object.keys(data.data.data).length > 0) {
            setSearchedEventTime(data.data.data[eventTimeId]);
          } else {
            alert("Event is not ongoing");
            props.history.push("/");
          }
        });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className="container"
      style={{ display: searchedEventTime.startTime ? "block" : "none" }}
    >
      <button onClick={() => setInvoice(true)}>Fizetés bankkártyával</button>
      <Dialog open={invoice} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <div>
          <form className="invoiceForm">
            <div className="invoiceFormContainer">
              <div className="invoiceFormContainer">
                <button>xxx</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(BuyTicket);
```

Comment: Please create a working example with the minimum relevant code. All the axios/localStorage/router and other things are completely not related to your question. You are really not new to StackOverflow, I think a bit more is expected.

Comment: The default type of a button in a form is "submit", so I suspect it is submitting your form and refreshing the whole page. Specify `type="button"`.